# Was there a travel section in the Sunday London Times in the 1890s?

Tags: victorian, london, newspapers

Was there a travel section in the Sunday edition of the *London Times* in the 1890s?  Or was there something that was roughly the equivalent of it?  If so, what was it called?  (Somehow "Travel" sounds too modern.)

Comment: Hi, welcome to History.SE! What research have you done so far? For example, have you discovered that the [_Sunday Times_ was a separate newspaper](https://www.thetimes.co.uk/static/about-us/) from the _Times_ until they were joined in 1966? Have you located (through your local public library, perhaps) the Gale _Sunday Times_ archives?